# Warning: include(Google/Client.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: magento-1.9, google-shopping-api

I've been working for the last couple days at trying to get to Google Shopping to work. I keep getting this error:

```html
Warning: include(Google/Client.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 56

#0 /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(56): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(Google/...', '/home/xxxx/...', 56, Array)
#1 /home/xxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(56): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Google_Client')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Google_Client')
#4 /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php(18): class_exists('Google_Client')
#5 /home/xxxx/public_html/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/autoload.php(29): require_once('/home/xxxx/...')
#6 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->{closure}('Google_Auth_Ass...')
#7 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/community/BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/GoogleShopping.php(107): spl_autoload_call('Google_Auth_Ass...')
#8 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/community/BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/controllers/Adminhtml/GoogleShoppingApi/ItemsController.php(53): BlueVisionTec_GoogleShoppingApi_Model_GoogleShopping->getClient('1')
#9 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(278): BlueVisionTec_GoogleShoppingApi_Adminhtml_GoogleShoppingApi_ItemsController->indexAction()
#10 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(200): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#11 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(116): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(189): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /home/xxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(415): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /home/xxxx/public_html/index.php(40): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

I've tried installing with composer and manually but nothing seems to work. Anyone knows what the problem is? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I moved the Google file to the root of my site, like Google/Client.php then in BlueVisionTec/GoogleShoppingApi/Model/GoogleShopping.php I changed the link to **require_once Mage::getBaseDir().'/Google/autoload.php';** and everything worked prefect.